# .tpl file not updating when changes are made

Tags: php, templates

I have been given a massive PHP e-commerce website to work on that is already mostly built, but I am currently having an issue regarding .tpl files. No matter what changes I make to the files, when they are saved the server will not update them (the files are staying saved, not reverting back to previous versions). My CSS changes and changes to PHP files are working but the core code within the .tpl files just doesn't want to play. I have seen a lot of places on the internet regarding these files in relation to something called smarty but I have not seen anything relating to that in this project and have just hit a brick wall.

Comment: `.tpl` files are _usually_ `Smarty` templates. Those templates get compiled and can be cached. Either set your cache-time to zero for your DEV environment or find out where the cached versions of those `.tpl` files are and remove them.

Comment: @kerbholz this worked! thank you

Comment: No problem, glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

After logging as Administrator, go to Configuration -> Performance -> Clear Cache
Click on Clear All Caches.
Once the Caches are cleared, the changes on the Template (tpl) files will be reflected.[image]